# Way to create a multi-module-project app in Angular (7x) ? For chrome ext

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension, multi-project

Is there is already a way to create a multi-project angular, so that I would have several index.html for reach project, but build them as one?

Having one dist folder with: dist/pr1 dist/pr2 dist/pr3

Basically, I need 3 AppComponents.

Why asking? Say, I want to build a chrome plugin.

Chrome plugin may have 3 entry points:

1. popupup.html,
2. content.html,
3. options.html

For PopUp, Content scripts and Options page respectively.

Because of that, it seems to me it has to be 3 applications. Each with its own index.tml.

(But then I will end up with overhead of having duplicated code/config + extra scripts to compile all to single /dist)

These two questions:

1. does it support a multi-project app, as I described?
2. is there a nicer way to create those chrome ex artifacts all with angular?

Comment: Depending on the size of the overhead, you can probably just ignore it.

Comment: 160kb for each app.